# Integrate with SCF service throwns 'EndpointNotFoundException' exception

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I try to integrate with WCF service from .net standard 2.0 project and I receive the following exception:

```
{System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://X.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

I checked the endpoint and it is correct and I tried to initialize the binding manually:

```
var wsHttpBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
wsHttpBinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.Default;
wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas = XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
wsHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
wsHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000);
wsHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 50000000;
wsHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 50000000;
wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 50000000;
wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 50000000;
wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 50000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are two ways when invoking the web service in Asp.net core project.

1. Adding the service reference to invoke the service.
2. Use the Channel Factory to generate the service instance in order to invoke the method.

Whichever method we use, we need to specify the service endpoint so that we could find where the service resides. Now the latest NetCore project uses the Microsoft WCF WEB Service Reference provider tool to add a service reference, just like the in the NetFramework project.

[image]

- [Official Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)
- [GitHub Reference](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/WCF-Web-Service-Reference-notes.md)

In that specific case, the generated ConnectedService file will contain the service endpoint.
[image]

If we use the use the ChannelFactory  to call the service.  you could refer to the following code.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9001/service1.svc");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            IService1 service = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result = service.GetData(100);
```